# Can you define string length in TypeScript interfaces?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a struct like so:

```
struct tTest{
  char foo [1+1];
  char bar [64];
};
```

In TypesScript I have

```js
export interface tTest{
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}
```

Is there a way to add [64] and [1+1] to the type?

Comment: No, there's nothing for that in js/ts. But what are you trying to do? To limit the length of the strings or do they should have a fixed size?

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with what `[1+1]` would actually do, but it sounds to me like the right way to do that in Typescript would be to define a `class tTest` with a `get foo(): string` method which returns your padded/truncated value.

Comment: 'char' isn't a type in JS nor TS, only string exists. What you can do is either limit the length of strings, or use an array of integers where each entry represents a character.

Comment: @NitzanTomer They need to have fixed length. Let's say foo should have length 64. If the string I pass to foo only has a length of 43, I need this to be adjusted by adding stuff (ASCIIZ e.g.). So that every foo, no matter what I pass into my interface, is of length 64. Is this clear? I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Wrt. struct support in TypeScript: See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24007

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the comments say: js/ts don't support the char type and there's no way to declare array/string lengths.

You can enforce that using a setter though:

```
interface tTest {
    foo: string;
}

class tTestImplementation implements tTest {
    private _foo: string;

    get foo(): string {
        return this._foo;
    }

    set foo(value: string) {
        this._foo = value;

        while (this._foo.length < 64) {
            this._foo += " ";
        }
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20tTest%20%7B%0D%0A%09foo%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20tTestImplementation%20implements%20tTest%20%7B%0D%0A%09private%20_foo%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09get%20foo()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20this._foo%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09set%20foo(value%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this._foo%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09while%20(this._foo.length%20%3C%2064)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09this._foo%20%2B%3D%20%22%20%22%3B%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D))

You'll need to have an actual class as the interfaces lacks implementation and doesn't survive the compilation process.
I just added spaces to get to the exact length, but you can change that to fit your needs.

Comment: I was afraid I'd need to do this.. But thanks to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't force the length of an array in Typescript, as you can't in javascript.
Let's say we have a class tTest as following:

```
class tTest{
       foo = new Array<string>(2);
};
```

As you can see, we have defined an array of string with length 2, with this syntax we can restrict the type of values we can put inside our array:

```
let t = new tTest();
console.log('lenght before initialization' +  t.foo.length);

for(var i = 0; i < t.foo.length; i++){
    console.log(t.foo[i]); 
}

t.foo[0] = 'p';
t.foo[1] = 'q';
//t.foo[2] = 3; // you can't do this
t.foo[2] = '3'; // but you can do this

console.log('length after initialization' +  t.foo.length);

for(var i = 0; i < t.foo.length; i++){
    console.log(t.foo[i]); 
}
```

In this manner we can't put a number value inside your array, but we can't limit the number of values you can put inside.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20tTest%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foo%20%3D%20new%20Array%3Cstring%3E(2)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20t%20%3D%20new%20tTest()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log('lenght%20before%20initialization'%20%2B%20%20t.foo.length)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afor(var%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20t.foo.length%3B%20i%2B%2B)%7B%0D%0A%09console.log(t.foo%5Bi%5D)%3B%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log('****')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0At.foo%5B0%5D%20%3D%20'p'%3B%0D%0At.foo%5B1%5D%20%3D%20'q'%3B%0D%0A%2F%2Ft.foo%5B2%5D%20%3D%203%3B%20%2F%2F%20you%20can't%20do%20this%0D%0At.foo%5B2%5D%20%3D%20'3'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log('lenght%20after%20initialization'%20%2B%20%20t.foo.length)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afor(var%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20t.foo.length%3B%20i%2B%2B)%7B%0D%0A%09console.log(t.foo%5Bi%5D)%3B%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%20)

Comment: Limiting the number of values doesn't fit my needs.. Looks like I have to do what I don't want to. But thanks to you aswell!